# duplicate records from postgresql sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

Could anyone help me while running query in Postgresql. I'm getting a duplicate record.

```
SELECT a.id, b.parameter_id
FROM products a
LEFT JOIN products_parameters b ON b.product_id = a.id 
WHERE a.category_id = 14 AND b.parameter_id = 22
ORDER BY a.id
```

Result - duplicated rows:

[image]

My data from table products:

```
SELECT *
FROM "products"
WHERE "id" = '10'
```

[image]

My data from table products_parameters:

```
SELECT *
FROM "products_parameters"
WHERE "product_id" = '10'
```

[image]

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want duplicates, the simplest solution is to use `select distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, pp.parameter_id
FROM products a JOIN
     products_parameters pp
     ON pp.product_id = p.id 
WHERE p.category_id = 14 AND pp.parameter_id = 22
ORDER BY p.id;
```

Your question doesn't have enough information to specify *why* you are getting duplicates, but presumably because you are only choosing one column from each of the tables and other columns are different.

Note the other changes to the query:

- The table aliases are *meaningful* rather than arbitrary letter.
- The `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an inner join anyway, so this version properly expresses the `JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Query not duplicate rows with DISTINCT, but i didn't understand why this rows duplicates :)